# What's the best way to handle different single quotes (’) and (') using jQuery/Perl/Mechanize?

Tags: javascript, jquery, perl, forms, mechanize

I have a form in Html that I'm submitting with jQuer.ajax to a Perl script that uses Mechanize to process the form on an URL and everything works well, except for the fact that when I see the info that's sent to the receiving URL, the character (`’`) get's stored as (`â`), I'm not sure what's the best way to handle it, I tried JavaScript's escape(), encodeURI(), replacing (`’`) from jQuery before sending everything through ajax, but I'm not sure if it get's treated as the other single quote (`'`). I can use a JavaScript/jQuery solution or do something with Perl, I'm just not sure how should I handle it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

«`’`» is RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK (U+2019). Its UTF-8 encoding is `E2 80 99`.

If you treat `E2 80 99` as iso-8859-1 or as Unicode code points, you get

1. LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH CIRCUMFLEX (â)
2. Unnamed control character.
3. Unnamed control character.

This is what you are seeing. You have an encoding problem.

Comment: This is very informative and I appreciate it, but besides pointing out what's wrong, it doesn't help me to correct it...

Comment: @darkajax: We can show you how to correct your code when you show us your code.

Comment: The problem is on line 42. (i.e. You need to help yourself first. We can't find your mistake if we don't know what you did. Please provide a minimal runnable snippet that demonstrates the problem.)

Comment: Ok, I'll try to put something together (I have multiple files with lots of lines, so it should take a while), and thanks for the all the advice.

Answer (score 0):

I would think this would be more of a problem with encoding (e.g. Unicode, ASCII, etc.) between the languages more-so than an escaping issue.  I would look to see what is the encoding standards between languages and you'll probably have to convert between two prior to passing the value(s) between the languages.

Edit:  As I stated previously, it's an encoding problem:

http://ecmanaut.blogspot.com/2006/07/encoding-decoding-utf8-in-javascript.html
http://ahinea.com/en/tech/perl-unicode-struggle.html